# Advantages/disadvantages of storing an Integer instead of the actual string in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been asked to re-design an existing database and one of things I've noticed is that they store all their dropdown values as strings rather than int.

As a habit, I've always store the combo values in one table and associated each string with a specific Id and store the Id value in the metadata table that is used searching. An `INNER JOIN` is then used when searching for the relevant value, but I thought check first to see if there are scenarios out there were you are better of storing the string.

The obvious flaws that come to mind when storing a `string` instead of an `int` are:

- Poor normalization.
- Larger table size.
- Slower update if specific column value needs to be renamed.

The points I'm not sure about are (on a large scale i.e. millions of records):

- Is there any reason why you would a store string rather than an integer apart from the 3 points I've just mentioned.
- How are indexes affected by this? Larger? Slower?
- Is it faster to run a query directly against a specific string rather than using a `INNER JOIN` against another table to match the relevant string against the integer value that is associated with this relevant string?
- Is there any kind of "Rule of thumbs" I should be aware of?

Is there other advantages or disadvantages I should be aware of when using one method or the other?

Comment: I would stick to your habit. Your obvious flaws are spot on.

Answer (score 0):

- Integers can be stores as strings - In case of storing amount values in a column and need to maintain the commas in between the integer values (10,000) you can use string column, as integer ignores commas

  In case of maintaining trending zeros in the value, string column can be used. The unwanted decimal zeros will be truncated while using integer column
- Indexes are created to tune the data retrieval from the database. While creating indexes on integer column is little faster compared to number column like wise compared with string columns.

  These variation in time limit is just a millisecond difference. It will not make a big difference even you change your string column to integer. But still if you need to change, you can just convert the indexing data type with the query

  ```
    CREATE INDEX INDEX_NAME ON COLUMN_NAME(TO_NUMBER(COLUMN_NAME))
  ```
- Using joins are the fastest approach to retrieve data from the database rather than using sub queries

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to store integers as string but instead of strings. Imagine you have an Orders table, and it contains 5 orders for "Hamburgers" for example. Rather than creating 5 rows with its ProductName set to "Hamburger", I would instead set the ProductId to the Id associated with "Hamburger" from the Products table. This is the part I'm asking as to whether or not it is always better to store the ProductId or is it better sometimes to just store the actual string i.e. Hamburger in this case. Is that making more sense?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to normalisation:

So long as each column of a given table depends on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key, you probably don't have normalisation issues.

Let's say you've got a table containing country names `country`. There's no need to add a surrogate key (e.g. integer id) to that table - a perfectly good key exists in the real world (see what I did there). Single column = `country_name`

Let's say you've got another table called `city` with two columns: `country_name`, `city_name`. The key for that table is simply both columns. You need a foreign-key constraint where `city.country_name` references `country.country_name`. Without that you might run into normalization issues.

The advantage of having `country_name` directly in the `city` table is that you don't have to perform a join. The disadvantage is that if the country name ever changes you have to update a bunch of city rows. There's also the consideration of the additional table width (bytes) and index width (bytes). Depending on how wide your table is already this may/may not be a problem.